# How to know when mysql database needs to be scaled up?

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-rds

I've got a unique use case: a social network where everyone comes to it all at once, a few times a day, and then goes away.

When they come, they do the typical reads and writes: liking photos, commenting, browsing photos etc. The photos are hosted on S3, so I've only got text data in the database.

I'm powering it using a MySQL db hosted on Amazon RDS.

As my users grow, I'd like to know which database statistic to monitor during these "high usage" events to make sure I'm not nearing the database's capacity. If I am, I'd like to scale up before this next "high usage" event happens. Amazon RDS makes scaling up pretty easy :)

At first I thought I'd look at the number of simultaneous connections, but how would I know what the limit is?

CPU usage is always around 1% or so, so I'm sure that's not the right indicator.

Then we've got things like:

- storage space
- freeable memory
- write IOPS
- read IOPS
- queue depth
- replica lag
- write latency
- read latency

and a few others... I can list em all if you'd like.

I was initially looking for some kind of relative % indicator so I would know to scale up if I hit let's say 80% of that number. But it looks like it'll be more complex than that...

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: You might find it easier to get an answer on dba.stackexchange so I've raised a migration vote for this.

Answer (score 1):

A simple strategy might be to look at average and maximum query response times, as well as query response times relative to number of queries per second.  If the latter graph starts curving upwards significantly under actual loads, and the problem isn't due to inefficient design and lack of optimization, then you may be reaching the limits of the DBMS.